# Как правильно сделать импорт xls в Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Уже не раз сталкиваюсь с этой задачей. Суть задачи - импорт xls файлов в базу данных.

Алгоритм:

1. Загрузка файла (происходит быстро 1-2 секунды)
2. Парсинг файла (аналогично быстро, 2-3 секунды)
3. Вставка в базу (долго, 1000 запросов - около 40 секунд)

3-й пункт как правило ускорял за счет того, что не использовал ActiveRecord, а составлял массив запросов и вставку делал пачкой. Например:

```
$sql = [];
for ($i = 1; $i < $total; $i++) {
    $sql[] = 'update products set ....';
}
$query = Yii::$app->db->createCommand(implode(",", $sql));
```

Это решало проблему до того времени, пока не стала нужда использовать ActiveRecord. Объясню почему: в 3-м пункте мне надо не просто обновить данные, а проверить есть ли запись, если да - то обновить, если нет - добавить, а после этого еще сохранить отдельно переводы. То есть, для последнего действия мне нужен id товара. Пример кода:

```
$model = Products::findOne(['code' => 111]);
if (empty($model)) { $model = new Product(); }
// тут присваиваем данные
if ($model->save()) { 
    $translation = Translation::find()->where(['table' => 'products', 'id' => $model->id, 'field' => 'name');
    if (empty($translation)) { $translation = new Translation(); }
    // данные для перевода
}
```

Подскажите, как можно улучшить этот код? Или это только с настройками БД играть?

Comment: *в 3-м пункте мне надо не просто обновить данные, а проверить есть ли запись, если да - то обновить, если нет - добавить* INSERT .. ODKU.

Comment: вы слишком много читаете: $model = Products::findOne(['code' => 111]); Выберите все id продуктов,и дальше смотрите на то, есть он, или нет

Comment: я читаю, что бы создать модель и обновить данные

Comment: ну так сделайте не N запросов, а 1

Comment: как сделать это 1 запросом?

Comment: собрать в массив все id, и сделать findAll по id

Comment: `Вариант 1` Написать функцию на стороне БД в которую пачкой (например в виде `json`) передать все данные. Функция внутри себя реализует тот же алгоритм с поиском и обновлением или вставкой по всему списку данных. Все это будет работать в разы быстрее т.к происходит на стороне сервера БД. `Вариант 2` использовать так называемый `INSERT OR UPDATE` (синтаксис отличается в зависимости от выбранной СУБД), например для `mysql` - [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html]
`

Comment: 40 секунд для импорта это разве много? Бывает импорт и по несколько минут идёт. Если импорт делается пользователями на фронте, то отправляем в очередь задачу, она дёргает консольный экшин который выполняет импорт. Если нужно показывать прогресс юзеру, создать в базе какую-то табличку в которую писать статус выполнения импорта.